# How can I use more than one @RequestParam annotations?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

How do I use `@RequestParam` to bind one parameters of type `String` which is *mandatory* and another one which is of type `Map<String, String>` which is *optional* ?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsers(@RequestParam(name = "mandatory") String mandatory,
          @RequestParam(required = false) Map < String, String > optional) 
    throws Exception {
       return userService.getUsers(mandatory, optional);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to simply indicate that the "mandatory" parameter is required, you must add the required = true as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUsers(@RequestParam(name = "mandatory", required = true) String mandatory,
          @RequestParam(required = false) Map < String, String > optional) 
    throws Exception {
       return userService.getUsers(mandatory, optional);
   }
```